# Problem with margins and tables

Tags: tables

Here is a picture of my problem :

[image]

As you can see, the table isn't well centered at all. I'd like the distance from the left margin to be equal to the distance from the right margin.
Here is my latex code:

```
\begin{table*}[h!] \centering
\caption{Cette table indique pour chaque méthode si elles sont statistiquement meilleures qu'un classeur ne prédisant que la classe dominante pour la base de données "Nombre d'enfants".}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} % 7 colonnes
\hline
\textbf{Méthodes} & LapRLS & LapRKLS & LRreglog & Autolog & BagOfPath & RCTK % premiere    colonne
\\ \hline
\textbf{>=0.5501} & 5 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 5
\\ \hline\hline
SVM & SVMmoran & SVMgeary & LogisticReg & Logmoran & Loggeary & MultiVarLog
\\ \hline
5 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Does anyone know how could I solve this problem ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Scipion How about adjusting your margin?

Comment: In addition to other comments, don't use `[h!]` It stops latex putting tlhe float in all float areas so makes it likely to go to the end of the document. (LaTeX warns about this and changes it to `[!ht]` But even that does not allow `p`age floats.

Comment: Also you have used `table*` `h` does not work at all with two-column floats

Answer (score 3):

It usually gives a more consistent appearance if you choose a defined document font size such as `\footnotesize` rather than scaling the table.  I also used `array` package to give extra padding below the horizontal lines, and used `table` rather than `table*`. Please always give complete documents showing the class and all packages used. The font size here is suitable for `article` class A4, but may not be right for other page sizes, but your example does not give that information.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Cette table indique pour chaque méthode si elles sont statistiquement meilleures qu'un classeur ne prédisant que la classe dominante pour la base de données "Nombre d'enfants".}

\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} % 7 colonnes
\hline
\textbf{Méthodes} & LapRLS & LapRKLS & LRreglog & Autolog & BagOfPath & RCTK % premiere    colonne
\\ \hline
\textbf{>=0.5501} & 5 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 5
\\ \hline\hline
SVM & SVMmoran & SVMgeary & LogisticReg & Logmoran & Loggeary & MultiVarLog
\\ \hline
5 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your table is too wide. The best way is to adjust the arrangement of your table contents. But if you don't want to change the arrangement, Here is a solution:

```
...
\leavevmode\hbox to 0pt{\hss
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} % 7 colonnes
...
\end{tabular}
\hss}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

needs package `graphicx`

```
...
\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} % 7 colonnes
  ...
  \end{tabular}%
}
...
```

or if you do want want to resize it:

```
...
\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} % 7 colonnes
  ...
  \end{tabular}%
}
...
```